# Assigning values from list to list excluding nulls

Tags: c#

Sorry for the title but I don't know other way of asking.

EDITED FOR EASY EXPLANATION

```
public Dictionary<string, string>[] getValuesDB(DataSet ds)
    {

        Dictionary<string, string>[] info; 
        Dictionary<string, string>[] temp = new Dictionary<string, string>[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
        Dictionary<string, string> d;

        string ciclo = "CICLO 02";

        try
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; c++)
            {
                d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                OracleConn ora = OracleConn.getInstancia();
                DataSet oraDs = ora.getClientByCycle(ds.Tables[0].Columns["IDCliente"].Table.Rows[c].ItemArray[1].ToString(), ciclo);

                if (oraDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    oraDs.Tables[0].Columns[5].Table.Rows[0].ToString();
                    d.Add("DomID", ds.Tables[0].Columns["DomID"].Table.Rows[c].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                    d.Add("ClientID", ds.Tables[0].Columns["ClientID"].Table.Rows[c].ItemArray[1].ToString());
                    d.Add("AccountType", ds.Tables[0].Columns["AccountType"].Table.Rows[c].ItemArray[2].ToString());
                    temp[c] = d;
                }
             }

        }
        catch (Exception eo)
        {

        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] != null)
                count++;
        }

        info = new Dictionary<string, string>[count];

        return info;
```

***NOW I need to get all the non-null values from 'temp' and put it in info***
Any idea

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you're asking. Do you want a new dictionary where all keys have non-null values?

Comment: Its not clear what data structures are you using. Can you post code that declares them?

Comment: You say you have two `<string,string>` dictionaries, but your code shows `temp` can be indexed with a int.  Please clarify.

Comment: It is not compulsory to initialize `Dictionary` with a size, like an `Array`. Along with, you do not have to do all this, when you have `LINQ` available.

Comment: You have an array of dictionaries, which is almost certainly not what you want.  You probably want either a SortedDictionary (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) or just a Dictionary (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), depending on whether order matters.

Comment: You people are focusing in the dictionary but my real problem is getting the values from a variable which has a different size.

Comment: GutierrezDev, one reason I'm mentioning the array is that it will make querying more complicated.

Comment: you donot have loop through all items as you would have to in older .Net Frameworks and classes. I would suggest you to have a look at `LINQ`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397906.aspx

Comment: Sorry to tell at this time, but Im using .net 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple Answer

A simple, direct, not-pretty answer that works with .NET 2.0 and disturbs as little code as possible:

```
// ...code
info = new Dictionary<string, string>[count];

// Beginning of new code
int j = 0;
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> fromTemp in temp)
{
    if (fromTemp == null)
        continue;
    info[j] = fromTemp;
    j++;
}
// End of new code

return info;
```

## Better Answer

However, there are several problems with your code snippet that should be corrected.  Please forgive me if you already know these things and just did not do them for the sake of brevity.  If that's the case, hopefully someone else will be able to learn from these comments.

### 1. The return type: `Dictionary<string, string>[]`

An array of dictionaries isn't very self explanatory and doesn't seem very useful. Dictionaries are perfect for looking up a value by a key, but once you place a bunch of these dictionaries in an array and remove the nulls, it seems like it would be pretty difficult to figure out which dictionary you need.

Since I don't know what you plan to do with the result of this method, it's hard to recommend an alternative.  Maybe try an `IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>>`, using `ds.Tables[0].Columns["IDCliente"].Table.Rows[c].ItemArray[1].ToString()` for the key of the outer dictionary.  That would make it easier to locate values in the result.  Or you could try an `IList<IDictionary<string, string>>`.  Either of those would be able to auto-resize as you add new elements, eliminating the need to count the non-nulls and allocate a new array.  Auto-resizing hurts performance, so initialize the collection with an appropriate capacity if you can.

#### Edit

After reviewing your code again, it appears that each dictionary gets the same three keys.  It would be more appropriate to use a class for this:

```
public class ClientInfo
{
    private string _domID;
    public string DomID
    {
        get { return _domID; }
        set { _domID = value; }
    }

    // ... also add properties for ClientID and AccountType
}
```

Then the return value could be something like `IList<ClientInfo>`.

### 2. Querying the database inside a loop

I'm guessing that `ora.getClientByCycle(...)` is a database query.  It's almost always possible to rewrite your query or batch queries together so that you only have to make one round-trip to the database.  Even if it's a fast query it's still probably going to be the slowest line in this method.  Query the database once rather than `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count` times.

### 3. Swallowing `System.Exception`

```
// !!! Don't do this!!!
catch (Exception eo)
{ }
```

If the database query might fail in certain cases and you're OK with that, then `catch (OracleException)`.  Always catch the most specific exception you can.  Otherwise the catch block could catch and ignore other exceptions that you weren't expecting.  Then your program doesn't behave correctly and you have no helpful exception information to help you debug it.  For more information, see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx.

Comment: WOW. Thanks. The simple answer worked very good.
2-Querying the database inside a loop: I knew it could be the slowest way but right now is the quickest way to do it (because the time). This project was not developed by me so Im changing or fixing things for a while.

3-System.Exception: It was for brevity, so I will add its respective catch block.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryWithoutNulls ;

dictionaryWithoutNulls = dictionaryWithNulls
                        .Where(d => d.Value != null)
                        .ToDictionary(s=>s.Key, s=>s.Value);
```

Comment: Because it is not designed for 2.0

Comment: Lol. Will this extract one by one every non-null? or will I need a counter?

Comment: @GutierrezDev: You need no counter mate. `dictionaryWithoutNulls` hold only those keyValuePairs from old dictionary, where values are not null, as per your question states!!!

Comment: Try above examples and then try this  `dictionaryWithoutNulls.Keys.Count;` and `dictionaryWithoutNulls.Values.Count;`